# useRouter is null; router.isready does not seem to work with nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

Im trying out next js 13 and I got some error I cant fix.
My code:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

async function getCheckoutInfo() {
    const router = useRouter();
    if (router.isReady) {
        console.log('Router query:', router.query);
    } else {
        console.log('Router is not ready yet')
    }
    
    return 'test';
}


export default async function CheckoutPage() {
    const info = await getCheckoutInfo();

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Checkout </h1>
            <p>{info}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My error msg:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Call Stack
Object.useContext
webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react/cjs/react.shared-subset.development.js (1428:31)
useRouter
webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/navigation.js (91:32)
```

What's wrong here? To me, it looks like useRouter doesn't work as intended. Previously I used useEffect() which worked fine but with nextjs 13 you don't need to do this I suppose: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-router

Thanks in advance for solving this mystery for me.

Comment: there were some breaking changes in Next.js 13, `router.isReady` was removed in the new `useRouter`. see this [upgrade guide](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide#step-5-migrating-routing-hooks)

Comment: are you adding `'use client';` at the top of the file or any parent? useRouter only works on client components

Answer (score 3):

with NextJS 13 router.ready is not available, they only having the following methods

```
router.push
router.replace
router.refresh()
router.prefetch
router.back()
router.forward()
```

for your case to get `query` values use the hook `useSearchParams`

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';


export default async function CheckoutPage() {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Checkout </h1>
            <p>{searchParams.toString()}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the new **App Directory** then, React Components are classified in two : Server and Client Components (as in here https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components), and by default, they are React Server Components.

Components using hooks (useRouter, useEffect, use...) are classified as Client Components and you need to add the "use client" directive at the top of the file (before any imports) (as the convention https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#client-components).
So, your code should be like this:

```
'use client';

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

//... rest of the code
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call `useRouter()` only inside the Top level of your React function component.

Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns.

Learn more about Rules of Hooks here : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Try something like this,

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function getCheckoutInfo(router) {
    if (router.isReady) {
        console.log('Router query:', router.query);
    } else {
        console.log('Router is not ready yet')
    }
    
    return 'test';
}


export default function CheckoutPage() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const info = getCheckoutInfo(router);

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Checkout </h1>
            <p>{info}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I run your code which gave an error sadly:
```Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isReady')``` 
Router is still undefined.

Comment: import useRouter from 'next/router';